# How to pass variable one page to another page in php

Tags: php, jquery

I need pass variable one page to another page in php,I got post data i have to pass the data to another file how to pass that variable please some one help me.i want pass variable product.php file to pinterest.php file please help.
Here my product.php file code:

```
//--------Post image-------///
       if (isset($this->request->post['image'])) {
                $data['image'] = $this->request->post['image'];
            }
              $images2 = "http://localhost/mspink_new/image/".$data['image'];
            //print_r($images2);die;
//--------Post image-------//
//-------------curl starting---------------//
                $url = 'http://localhost/mspink_new/pintest.php';
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$images2);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                print_r($result);die;
                curl_close($ch);
//-------------curl clossing---------------//
```

Here my pinterest.php file:

```
$images = $_POST['image'];
require_once "Pinterest.class.php";
$p = new Pinterest();
$p->login("username", "password");
if( $p->is_logged_in() )
    echo "Success, we're logged in\n";

$image =$images;
$p->pin_url = "http://www.websitname/";
$p->pin_description = "My awesome pin";
$p->pin_image_preview = $p->generate_image_preview('slider.jpg');
// Get the boards
$p->get_boards();
// Pin to the board called "Items"
if( !isset($p->boards['Items']) ) {
    echo "For testing, please create a board called 'Items' and try again!\n";
    exit;
}
$p->pin($p->boards['Items']);
// And we're done
echo "Hooray!\n";
```

Comment: Hi all, I have to pass product.php file  variable $images2 to pinterest.php file

Comment: Are you trying to send an object ($data['image']) through the URI?

Comment: not try sir how will send sir

Comment: Why don't you handle all your logic on one page? You could also include the pinterest.php file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please note that you are referencing different names for the file pinterest.php. in your curl you call .../pintest.php and you say your file is called pinterest.php

Secondly, you needlessly reassign this variable.

```
$image =$images;
```

I thin in your case it is best to include / require_once the  pinterest.php file:

```
// Post image
if (isset($this->request->post['image'])){ $data['image'] = $this->request->post['image']; 
include('pintest.php');
}
```